# Convert integers to string and then adding using recursion

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, int, tostring

Hi I am trying to solve a problem where the input for a function digital_root(n) will add the digits. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```js
function digital_root(n) {
  // ...
  //1. separate n into array of digits

  var nString = n.toString();

  //[ '1', '2', '3', '4' ]
  var numbersToAdd = [];

  var total = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < nString.length; i++) {
    numbersToAdd.push(+nString.charAt(i));
  }
  // result is [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
  //2. add digits
  for (var x = 0; x < numbersToAdd.length; x++) {
    total += numbersToAdd[i];
    //expected outputs
    // total = 0 + numbersToAdd[0]--> 0+1--> total = 1
    // total = 1 + numbersToAdd[1]-->1+2--> total = 3
    // total = 3 + numbersToAdd[2]-->3+3--> total = 6
    // total = 6 + numbersToAdd[3]-->6+3--> total = 9
  }

  return total;

}

console.log(digital_root(1234));
```

Comment: There's no recursion here.

Comment: Your index is `i` while your `for` variable is `x`

Comment: @GalAbra He's casting them to integers with `+nString.charAt(i)`.

Comment: You don't have any recursion, but an incorrect variable as index.  `total += numbersToAdd[i];` change to `x` - `total += numbersToAdd[x];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use "x" instead of "i"

So changing

```
total += numbersToAdd[i];
```

to

```
total += numbersToAdd[x];
```

will fix an issue.

Also output should be 10 instead of 9, there is calculation mistake in your question